# Allow users to annotate content in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

Is there any way to allow users to add some private annotations when reading a book page for example ?

It seems that [the annotate module](http://drupal.org/project/annotate) is not anymore supported.

Comment: There's a 7.x version on the link (to the annotate module) that you provided and it's in dev. I don't see how you can't use that.

Comment: How about the Flags module?

Answer (score 2):

The book [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/) is probably the most popular book for learning how to build Drupal modules. In the 3rd edition, which covers Drupal 7, the author uses the **Annotate** module as an example of how to build a module from scratch.

If you read the first chapters of the book you could easily write the module yourself, or even better, try to port the [module you mention](http://drupal.org/project/annotate) to 7.x. By the way, remember to check [Errata of the book](http://www.drupalbook.com/errata3) first.